# Enum _missing_ function not silencing ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I'm trying to set up an Enum that will return `None` if the value is not found. The documentation mentions a function `_missing_`, but does not explain any of the details regarding the function:

> [`_missing_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#supported-sunder-names) – a lookup function used when a value is not found; may be overridden

After some looking around, it seems this is a `classmethod` with the signature `cls, value`, so I tried to set it up, and its not working.

```
>>> class G(enum.Enum):
...   @classmethod
...   def _missing_(cls, value):
...     return None
...   a = 1
...
>>> G(1)
<G.a: 1>
>>> G(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: 2 is not a valid G
>>> G['b']
KeyError: 'b'
>>> G.b
AttributeError: b
```

A google search suggests that `_missing_` only catches the ValueError in the call case, so the KeyError and TypeError do not surprise me, but I do not know why `G(2)` is raising ValueError instead of returning `None`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 2 main things that the documentation is missing regarding the `_missing_` function is the signature in the question, and the fact that the return type MUST be a member of the Enum. If `None` is returned, then the error simply isn't silenced.

This behaviour is only seen through source inspection or a different error message:

```
>>> class G(enum.Enum):
...   @classmethod
...   def _missing_(cls, value):
...     return "a truthy value"  # I suspected that the error may have been caused by a falsey return
...   a = 1
...
>>> G(2)
ValueError: 2 is not a valid G
During handling of the above exception, another exception occured:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: error in G._missing_: returned 'a truthy value' instead of None or a valid member
```

So the only way to handle this case is to have a sentinal `G.none`, `G.null`, `G.missing` or whatever value is most suitable.

Comment: Wow, how embarrassing!  I'll try to get a patch for that in the next few days.  Feel free to beat me to it!  :-)